# Why is my enum comparison not finding the proper value?

Tags: c#, enums

I am trying to find a specific Enum from a list of objects. Here is the code:

```
foreach (IEquipment eq in EntityEquipmentList)
{
if (eq.capability == capabilityEnum.Jam)
{
Console.WriteLine(eq.ToString())
}
}
```

Just to be clear, EntityEquipmentList is a List of IEquipment objects and I am trying to find the one that has "Jam" as it's capability. As you can see in the "if" statement, I want the capability of "Jam".

Enum in question:

```
Radar = 1
Jam = 2
Radio = 4
LowFreq = 8
HighFreq = 16
```

And to be clear, I am 100% certain that there is a piece of Equipment in the list with the Capability of Jam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the values in your capabilities enum are "powers of two" (1, 2, 4, 8, ... instead of 1, 2, 3, 4, ...). This is usually done for **flag enums**, where an enum value can be a *combination* of different defined values. For example, an equipment could have the capability of `Jammer` as well as `Radar`.

Well, now `Jammer + Radar` (or, to be precise: `Jammer | Radar`, using bitwise OR) is not equal to `Jammer`, which is why your comparison fails. You can fix this by using `HasFlag` instead of `Equals`:

```
if (equipmentCapability.HasFlag(CapabilityEnum.Jammer)) { ... }
```

---

In addition, you should add the [`Flags` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=net-6.0) to your enum. This

- documents the fact that these enum values can be combined, and also
- causes `equipmentCapability.ToString()` to output `Jammer, Radar` instead of the numerical value.

Comment: Thank you!! That is definitely it, it is a flag enum. Almost all of them do have multiple capabilities, I thought they were separate and not added. Thanks!!!